# what can a simple slideshow look like

Tags: javascript, slideshow

i have an example of a simple slideshow. unfortunately the transition to the last picture doesn't work as well as with the other two.

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

```css
#slideshow {
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 1229px;
  height: 858px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#slideshow>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div>
    <img src="https://as2.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/68/04/19/500_F_268041942_RPytRGKfSKx4Yk4NV0RZ0sqcpx8ZSEak.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://as2.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/68/04/19/500_F_268041959_VCKjqtEbr2te6x1P7z6g5xHYCFAnua6G.jpg">
  </div>
  <img src="https://as2.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/68/04/19/500_F_268041948_wv0NLtMeGfunrFb00kLYSokk1eYM2ygo.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

I can't find the error :(. Do you have an idea or even a better one. Thanks

Comment: What is the question, in the snippet above it seems to work properly.

Comment: The last image is not in a div.

Comment: See my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

```css
#slideshow {
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 1229px;
  height: 858px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#slideshow>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div>
    <img src="https://as2.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/68/04/19/500_F_268041942_RPytRGKfSKx4Yk4NV0RZ0sqcpx8ZSEak.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://as2.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/68/04/19/500_F_268041959_VCKjqtEbr2te6x1P7z6g5xHYCFAnua6G.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
  <img src="https://as2.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/68/04/19/500_F_268041948_wv0NLtMeGfunrFb00kLYSokk1eYM2ygo.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added <div> before your 3rd <img>

Comment: If you think this is the answer, Don't forget to check it as an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If it's simple. I think you can try this

```
https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/qiAyo
```

Only css and HTML.. so simple Idea

Explaining:

```
<Container>
  <Element 1 />
  <Element 2 />
  <Element 3 />
</Container>
```

Comment: His code works perfectly, so there is no need to change to css. There is only a mistake in the HTML